# List the account-number, balance, loan-number and amount address using left join

Tags: mysql, sql, database

so I have this question and i tried to solve it like this:

```
select account.account_number,account.balance loan.loan_number,loan.amount from account LEFT JOIN loan ON account.branch_name=loan.branch_name';
```

I have the tables as follow:
[table1:account,table2:loan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSaW6.png) .
it shos me this error.

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in 
your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near '';

select 
account.account_number,account.balance 
loan.loan_number,loan.amount f' at line1
```

and this one I honestly did not get it at all so if someone can explain to me how to solve it I will be thankful.
Find the total amount each branch has in accounts.
I have these tables as follows:[tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdG2y.png)
please help and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
select account.account_number,
       account.balance, --you missed one comma there
       loan.loan_number,
       loan.amount 
  FROM account 
  LEFT JOIN loan 
    ON account.branch_name=loan.branch_name; -- you had a extra single quote there
```

a good formatted code will help you find issue.

Comment: thank it worked, and I will take your advice to have a well-formatted code.

Comment: @ahad please 'accept' (and, optionally, upvote) this answer

Comment: I tried to upvote his answer from the moment it worked but it won't take my vote.